# Prevent notifications from other apps when specific app is running

Tags: iphone, ios, focus

I have a GPS app (Waze) and when it runs, I don't want to recieve any notifications from Messages, WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, Telegram, etc.

Actually I don't want to recieve any notifications except phone calls. Is it possible to be in a "Driving mode" on my phone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Do Not Disturb While Driving" mode will be available in iOS 11. So a few more months patience and you have the feature you want.

> “It’s all about keeping your eyes on the road,” Apple Senior Vice
>   President of Software Engineering Craig Federighi said when
>   introducing the feature at WWDC in June. “When you’re driving, you
>   don’t need to respond to these kind of messages. In fact, you don’t
>   need to see them"

Your iPhone will detect when it's in a driving car and put your phone on "Do Not Disturb While Driving" mode. You can also manually turn it on/off via Control Centre.

[image: Control Centre]

Comment: Great. Too bad it'll be lost in a sea of inscrutable little icons arranged haphazardly on the screen...

Comment: For most part it will work automatically. When your iPhone detects it's in a moving vehicle it will turn on "Do Not Disturb While Driving" mode.

Comment: What if I'm a passenger? I don't want to lose notifications when I'm not driving :/

Comment: You get an alert to verify if you are an passenger or not. More info about this feature: https://www.macrumors.com/2017/06/30/ios-11-do-not-disturb-while-driving/